# Prime Faces responsiveness layout 2017

Tags: layout, primefaces, themes, responsive

I have a question for experienced pf users, what is the best practise of creating site layouts, should i use frameworks like bootstrap and use it together with pf components or maybe i should create my own template. Another question does primefaces provide complete responsiveness for mobile devices? I have already learnt pf css grid but this is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap responsiveness does not differ that much from the PrimeFaces in terms of 'grid CSS' like things. But that is only a small part of the responsiveness. Components themselves should have responsiveness built into them to be really useful on devices with different screen real estate or there should be a different component set for other devices. Initially PrimeFaces create ["PrimeFaces Mobile"](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml) but you had to create different pages or one page with lots if 'if-then-else'rendering wise.

Luckily, they have been [adding 'responsiveness'](https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+responsive) to the existing components for several releases now and decided to [deprecate the PrimeFaces Mobile in 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-6-2-roadmap/) and drop it in 6.3.

The responsiveness of the normal components can still improve (I filed [two issued](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20author%3Akukel%20responsive))and they picked those up recently most likely do to the deprecation of mobile.

Regarding the 'improvement', their existing menu components e.g. are not responsive (yet? but no enhancement issues file either) but they have good [themes](https://www.primefaces.org/themes/) (layout/templates) on offer that do have responsive menu's in them (we use [Serenity](https://www.primefaces.org/serenity/) for which you can easily change the colors to fit your own needs)

Even though the themes are 'commercial', it saves you a decent amount of time and work so I do think they are a justified investigation.